# How do I add an exclamation mark to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add an ! to a name when it is printed. For example: *John!*

Comment: This is incredibly well documented all over the internet and is covered in any introductory tutorial/course. There is no reason to ask a question about this.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use `+` to add strings.
E.g.

```py
name = "John"
new_name = name + "!"
```

Comment: The question has been answered probably millions of times and is basic python skills. It's clearly a duplicate and there's no need to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add it when printing, you can format your output using f-string:

```
name = "John"
print(f"{name}!")
```

Comment: The question has been answered probably millions of times and is basic python skills. It's clearly a duplicate and there's no need to answer it.

Comment: Does this mean that f-strings should be avoided when not printing? Why?

Comment: Didnt say that. Printing just doesnt add ! to the variable.

Comment: So we can remove "If you only want to add it when printing" from the answer?

Comment: @mkrieger1 f-strings can be used for variable assignment as well, using + to add the ! or an f-string gives the same result, but f-strings aren't often used outside print statements since they are slower (in my testing adding is about 19% faster)